# C# Database Insert (ASP.NET) - ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

first time I'm doing an insert from ASP.NET/C# and I'm having a little issue. I keep getting the following error every time this code runs: " ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized" Does anyone know what this means and how I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO ATI_LOG_IO (Date, Connect_Time, Disconnect_Time, ATI_Rep, Reason_For_Access, Property_Contact, Case_Number, Comments, Property_ID)";
sqlQuery += "VALUES (@Today, @Connect, @Disconnect, @Rep, @Reason, @Contact, @CaseNum, @Comments, @PropertyID)";
using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        dataConnection.Open();
        dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Today", DateTime.Today.ToString());
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Connect", txtInDate.Text + " " + fromHrs.Text + ":" + fromMins.Text + ":00");
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Disconnect", txtOutdate.Text + " " + toHrs.Text + ":" + fromMins.Text + ":00");
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Rep", repID);
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Reason", txtReason.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Contact", txtContact.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@CaseNum", txtCaseNum.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comments", txtComments.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@PropertyID", lstProperties.SelectedValue);
        dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, Object)` is obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. Try These: using `@` -> `Parameters.Add(SqlParameter)`,`Parameters.AddRange(SqlParameter[])`or , Without `@` -> `Parameters.AddWithValue(String, Object)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO ATI_LOG_IO (Date, Connect_Time, Disconnect_Time, ATI_Rep, Reason_For_Access, Property_Contact, Case_Number, Comments, Property_ID)";
sqlQuery += " VALUES (@Today, @Connect, @Disconnect, @Rep, @Reason, @Contact, @CaseNum, @Comments, @PropertyID)";
using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dataConnection))
    {
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Today", DateTime.Today.ToString());
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Connect", txtInDate.Text + " " + fromHrs.Text + ":" + fromMins.Text + ":00");
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Disconnect", txtOutdate.Text + " " + toHrs.Text + ":" + fromMins.Text + ":00");
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Rep", repID);
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Reason", txtReason.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Contact", txtContact.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CaseNum", txtCaseNum.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comments", txtComments.Text);
        dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PropertyID", lstProperties.SelectedValue);

        dataConnection.Open();
        dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Copy-paste should do the trick

Comment: So from the look of it you've fixed my code with the above suggestions, that much I get, but (sorry if it's a noob question) what is the difference between Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue - and is the omission of my original @s a result of preference or was I in error to use them in the first place?

Comment: I have only used Parameters.Add(SqlParameter) overload of the method passing in preinstantiated parameter. The overload you were using is currently obsolete by Microsoft. I never had success using it either, in the past. As far as the @ sign, in VB I had to specify parameter name with @ sign, when using AddWithValue method, but in C# it's not required, but i think you could still get the same result using the @ sign with parameter name. If you'd rather use Parameters.Add, use Parameters.Add(String Name, SqlDbType Type) overload and then pass in value as Parameters["@Name"].Value=Value

Comment: That seems to have taken care of it. Now I get an error about not having INSERT permissions on that table, which is my own stupid fault and at least I know how to fix THAT one :)

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you haven't set the CommandText property, but in your case, you have.

You should try testing that the sqlQuery string is actually not empty at this line:

```
dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
```

P.S. As a "best practice", you may want to consider opening the connection AFTER setting up the SqlCommand object, to minimize the time spent with an open connection:

```
    dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@Today", DateTime.Today.ToString());
    //...
    dataConnection.Open();
    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dataConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I've tried opening it before and after setting up the object just in case it had something to do with the error, forgot to move it back before posting code. Thanks for the tip though :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your string sql query, you're not leaving a space between the "INTO" part and "VALUES" part.

```
...............Property_ID)";
sqlQuery += "VALUES (@Today, ..............
```

SHOULD BE:

```
...............Property_ID)";
sqlQuery += " VALUES (@Today, ..............
```

Comment: Oh dear, that would certainly cause some issues. Any idea if it would cause this specific issue? Does the dataCommand actually parse SQL before sending it or would it just result in a SQL error being returned once I fix the cause of *this* error?